# How to render a ginger template given template text and context with ToJSON?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use [ginger](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ginger) library. My attempt based on the library documentation:

```hs
renderTemplate :: ToJSON c => Text -> c -> Either Text Text
renderTemplate template ctx = do
  tpl <- tplEither
  let ctxGVal :: GVal Identity = rawJSONToGVal $ toJSON ctx
  let r :: Text = easyRender ctxGVal tpl
  return r
  where
    tplEither :: Either Text (Template SourcePos)
    tplEither = parseGinger nullResolver Nothing (toS template) & runIdentity & mapLeft tshow
    nullResolver :: IncludeResolver Identity
    nullResolver = const $ return Nothing
```

I am getting:

```
Could not deduce (ToGVal
                          (Text.Ginger.Run.Type.Run
                             SourcePos (Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Lazy.Writer Text) Text)
                          (GVal Identity))
        arising from a use of ‘easyRender’
```

I don't really understand what is going on. Why `GVal` needs a parameter at all? From the examples it looks to me it should be possible to render a template in a pure way.

How to modify my code so it compiles and works as intended (from given template and context produces text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to use `GVal (Run SourcePos (Writer Text) Text)` as the type of `ctxGVal` instead of `GVal Identity`.

The `rawJSONToGVal` function can produce any `GVal m` so you have to choose the `m` that is needed by the rendering function, your application of `easyRender` requires the type `Run SourcePos (Writer Text) Text`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Though I am still unsure why it's needed (why can't be it inferred if nothing else fits? it didn't work without explicit type either).

Comment: @menfon in this case there is only one instance that works: `ToGVal m (GVal m)` but in the future (or in another module) somebody might implement another instance like `ToGVal Identity (GVal m)` so then GHC wouldn't know what to choose. So, the ambiguity is due to the open-world nature of type classes in Haskell. Maybe this could be improved by changing the ginger library, but it is not obvious to me if that is possible.